# Interactive UML editor with API to create diagrams

Tags: api, uml, editor, interactive, class-diagram

I search for a free and interactive UML editor that have user-friendly API to create diagrams. I searched StarUml-v1 and ArgoUml and didn't manage to find such.

Background:

I'm trying to automate class diagram creation from C++ code into interactive editor (in contrary to some *.dot files GUI-viewers).

Based on [this project](https://github.com/gklingler/CodeDependencyVisualizer) I use clang to extract and filter data from the translation units (for instance filtering ::std classes), and need to generate output to some UML editor in order to create and edit class diagrams.

Any other suggestions to achieve such process (filtering code and turn it into class diagrams on a shiny UML editor) are welcome

Tnx

Comment: Your question is OT for SO. Please read SO's help on how to ask a (good) question.

Answer (score 1):

Try [YUML](https://yuml.me/). It generates a short URL and also an "editable URL" which is effectively an API.

Comment: This YUML thing is pretty cool, but I'm searching for interactive editor (in YUML the diagram is edited via code, not interactively). In addition, AFAIU the text itself can't be formatted so I can't use italic annotation for virtual methods etc.
Tnx!